# Tradução de vocabulário técnico em inglês

Tags: debate, tradução

É muitos comum estarmos familiarizados com termos técnicos em inglês, e sentir alguma dificuldade em encontrar as palavras corretas para nos expressarmos em português.

Talvez faça sentido criar um "dicionário" de termos onde possamos procurar a melhor forma de expressar em português um termo que costumamos usar em inglês, ou o inverso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode ser mesmo, porém acho que certos termos podem ser utilizados em inglês sem problemas. Um exemplo é "loop" – eu pessoalmente não gosto de "laço", e vejo muito mais gente usar "loop" que "laço". Isso vale para diversas expressões.

Mesmo assim, pode mesmo ser útil termos um post-dicionário ("post", não "postagem", hehe). Se você quiser começar um, crie uma pergunta aqui no meta, e inclua um esboço da lista como resposta. "Sinalize" (flag) a pergunta, escolhendo o tipo "outro" e pedindo para o moderador marcá-la como "wiki da comunidade".

Comment: Boa sugestão. Vale a pena sublinhar que termos em inglês podem perfeitamente ser usados. Pegando no seu exemplo, eu não saberia o que "laço" significa, estou mais acostumado com o termo "ciclo".

Comment: Isto é apenas uma curiosidade, mas eu sou Português de Portugal, e "[laço](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Bow-tie-colour-isolated.jpg)" é o que usamos no pescoço ao invés de uma gravata, ou também o que [colamos numa prenda](https://www.google.com/search?q=La%C3%A7o+de+Natal&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=J3mzUvqdFeqqyAPYjoGoAQ&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=913) depois de embrulhada. Efectivamente, aqui onde estou, "loop" é um "[ciclo](http://rolan2.home.sapo.pt/trabalhos/C_p5.pdf)". :)

Comment: @Zuul O "laço" de vocês aqui no Brasil é "gravata borboleta", e "prenda" é menos comum que "presente" :). "Ciclo" soa bem melhor que "laço", que já vi em livros e na web em Pt-br. Mas no dia-a-dia muita gente aqui diz "loop" mesmo. Aí não?

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, aqui, pelo menos com o pessoal com quem lido, se o termo técnico é "loop", dizemos "loop", traduzir essas coisas gera confusão... estarmos a dizer "ciclo" e a ler "loop" no ecrã só baralha! :)

Comment: Minha nossa... nunca tinha escutado nem *laço* nem *ciclo*... acho que em alguns momentos pra fazer a ponte `pt.pt` pra `pt.br`, só mesmo o `pt.en` ;)